# dynamic way to access json array elements

Tags: javascript, html, json

so i have json array

```
data = '[{"beatles": [
                {"name":"Paul McCartney","value": "http://www.paulmccartney.com"},
                {"name": "John Lennon","value": "http://www.johnlennon.it"},
                {"name":"George Harrison","value": "http://www.georgeharrison.com"},
                {"name": "Ringo Starr","value": "http://www.ringostarr.com"}],
           "stones": [
                {"name": "Mick Jagger","value": "http://www.mickjagger.com"},
                {"name": "Keith Richards","value": "http://www.keithrichards.com"}]'
```

and i have two dropdown lists

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
          <title></title>
          <script src="rockbands.json"></script>
          <script src="script.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body onload="getBands()">
          <select id="bands" onchange="getNames(this.value)"></select>
          <select id="names" ></select>

     </body>
</html>
```

so i load the dropdownlist with ID "bands" with this JS Code

```
function getBands() {
    var root = JSON.parse(data)
    var bandsBox = document.getElementById("bands")
    for(i in root[0]) {
        var option = document.createElement("option")
        option.text = i
        bandsBox.appendChild(option)
    }
}
```

what i want to do is populate the other dropdown list with ID "names"
with the array element "name" based on the selection in the first dropdownlist for example if i chose beatles it would load all names in beatles

i could access it with something like root[0].beatles[1].name but i want a dynamic way to access them thanks

Comment: thats not a json array, its a string.

Comment: ah yea sorry , json string thats what i meant

Comment: See this -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/05ejeunh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors):

> Property accessors provide access to an object's properties by using
>   the dot notation or the bracket notation.

```
object.property
object["property"]
```

Which means you can access properties like `root[0]['beatles'][1]['name']` as well.

And since 'beatles' is a string acting like property, it can be a variable too:

`root[0][band_name][1]['name']`

Answer (score 2):

in your `getNames()` function do something like

```
function getNames(nameOfBand) {
    var root = JSON.parse(data);
    var namesBox = document.getElementById("names");
    var listOfNames = root[0][nameOfBand]
    for( j = 0; j < listOfNames.length; j++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = listOfNames[j]["name"];
        namesBox.appendChild(option)
    }
}
```